# Are machines greater than suns too ridiculous for a science fiction setting?

Tags: science-fiction

I came across this quote of what Jodorowsky wanted for his Dune film:

> We saw ourselves enmeshed in these huge masses hurtling a dizzy train of planets from a dark world bound for a galaxy drowned in starry milk. We saw ourselves inside minute ether- dwelling sharks crossing seven thousand universes in one Terrene second, leaving a sound- wake freezing into a trail of hallucinatory pearls. Trains to carry away the whole of humanity; machines greater than suns wandering crazed and rusted, whimpering like dogs seeking a master. And great wings sucking the marrow of comets. And thinking wheels hidden behind meteorites, waiting, camouflaged as metallic rocks, for a drop of life to pass through those lost galactic fringes to slake thirsty tanks with psychic secretions. All this and more I wanted for Dune.

My question is, do you have any ideas as to how a situation like this could be seen as somewhat plausible?

Comment: Welcome! Please take a moment to review the [tour] and [help] and find out [what WB.SE is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) before you ask questions. Stack Exchange isn't really the place to ask "opinion based" questions! As you can see, here in Worldbuilding, our goal is to help you with problems or issues you're facing in your own worldbuilding projects. I don't usually vote to close opinion based queries -- because 96% of the questions here are opinion based in some way! -- but your query is pure opinion!

Comment: maybe this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rmb1tNEGwmo) can help or check matrioshka brain. i am not scientist thought, so i may get your question wrong, but i hope this help or informative for you.

Comment: What is plausible for one person might not be for another. I think you should do some research on suspension of disbelief.

Comment: Seems much closer to Cordwainer Smith's *[Drunkboat](https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/smithcordwainer-drunkboat/smithcordwainer-drunkboat-00-h.html)* (1963) than to *Dune*.

Comment: (a) [Jodorowsky is a nut](https://www.tor.com/2017/05/02/jodorowskys-dune-didnt-get-made-for-a-reason-and-we-should-all-be-grateful/). (b) Jodorowsky wasn't interested in adapting *Dune* to film, he was interested in being inspired by *Dune* to create another of his (in)famous psychoanalytical movies. The quote you provided didn't represent what he expected to have in the final script at all - it's nothing more than his stream-of-consciousness expression of creativity. And what you asked was if this (likely) LSD-saturated hallucination could actually be plausible. The answer, of course, is no.